# Adjacency-List Paths in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, path-finding, directed-graph, adjacency-list

If I have an adjacency list, represented in Scala like this:

```
val l = List(
    List((1, 1), (2, 3), (4, 10)),
    List((2, 1)),
    List((3, 1), (4, 5)),
    List(4, 1)),
    List())
```

Every "List" contains the costs of the path from one node to another in a directed graph. So the first "List" with three entries represents the successors of the first node (counting from 0). That means Node 0 directs to Node 1 with a cost of 1, to Node 2 with a cost of 3 and to Node 4 with a cost of 10 and so on.

How would it be possible to recursively compute if there are paths with a max cost from a given node to another? I thought of something like this:

```
def hasMaxCostPath: (List[List[(Int, Int)]], Int, Int, Int) => Int => Boolean = (adj, from, to, max) => len =>
```

So the function receives the adjacency list "adj", the start node "from", the end node "to", the max cost of the path "max" and the max length of the path "len". 
So I think the result should be like the following based on the above given adjacency list:

```
hasMaxCostPath(l, 0, 2, 2)(1) == false
hasMaxCostPath(l, 0, 2, 3)(1) == true
```

Furthermore how would it be possible to recursively compute a list of all costs of paths that go from one specified node to another within a given max length? Maybe like this:

```
def getPaths: (List[List[(Int, Int)]], List[(Int, Int)], Int, Int) => List[Int] =
(adj, vn, dest, len) =>
```

So this function would get the adjacency list "adj", a list of already visited nodes "vn" with (node, cost), in which we take the given node as the start node, the destination node "dest" and the max length of the path "len". And for this function the results could be like the following:

```
getPaths(l, List((0, 0)), 2, 1) == List(3)     // Node0 -> Node2
getPaths(l, List((0, 0)), 2, 2) == List(2, 3)  // Node0 -> Node1 -> Node2 AND Node0 -> Node2
```

Sorry, I'm very new to Scala

Comment: I don't see any scala-specific problems in this question. Looks more like a list of fairly basic graph algorithms that you didn't attempt to implement. Please show what you tried so far and explain where exactly you got stuck. If you don't know how to start, go and read *any* introductory book on graph algorithms. By the way: unlike in Haskell, it's uncommon in Scala to declare functions in the nameless completely curried form that you used in your question. Use normal method signatures with proper argument names instead.

Comment: Is this homework :-) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
package foo

object Foo {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val edges = List(
      List((1, 1), (2, 3), (4, 10)),
      List((2, 1)),
      List((3, 1), (4, 5)),
      List((4, 1)),
      List())
    println(hasMaxCostPath(edges,0,1,2))
    println(hasMaxCostPath(edges,0,2,2))
  }

  def hasMaxCostPath(edges: List[List[(Int, Int)]], start: Int, end: Int, maxCost: Int): Boolean = {
    maxCost > 0 &&
    edges(start).exists(a =>
      (a._1 == end && a._2 <= maxCost) ||
      hasMaxCostPath(edges, a._1, end, maxCost - a._2)
    )
  }

}
```

Edit: ====

The above solution did not take into account the length parameter. 
Here is a solution with the length parameter:

```
package foo

object Foo {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val edges = List(
      List((1, 1), (2, 3), (4, 10)),
      List((2, 1)),
      List((3, 1), (4, 5)),
      List((4, 1)),
      List())
      assert(! hasMaxCostPath(edges,0,4,4,3))
      assert(hasMaxCostPath(edges,0,4,4,4))
  }

  def hasMaxCostPath(edges: List[List[(Int, Int)]], start: Int, end: Int, maxCost: Int, maxLength: Int): Boolean = {
    maxLength > 0 &&
    maxCost >= 0 &&
    edges(start).exists(a =>
      (a._1 == end && a._2 <= maxCost) ||
      hasMaxCostPath(edges, a._1, end, maxCost - a._2, maxLength - 1)
    )
  }

}
```

=== Edit:

And here is a solution including your second problem:

```
package foo

object Foo {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val edges = List(
      List((1, 1), (2, 3), (4, 10)),
      List((2, 1)),
      List((3, 1), (4, 5)),
      List((4, 1)),
      List())
    assert(! hasMaxCostPath(edges,0,4,4,3))
    assert(hasMaxCostPath(edges,0,4,4,4))
    assert(getMaxCostPaths(edges,0,0,5,5) == List())
    assert(getMaxCostPaths(edges,0,1,1,1) == List(List(0,1)))
    assert(getMaxCostPaths(edges,0,2,2,2) == List(List(0,1,2)))
    assert(getMaxCostPaths(edges,0,2,5,5) == List(List(0,2), List(0,1,2)))
  }

  def hasMaxCostPath(edges: List[List[(Int, Int)]], start: Int, end: Int, maxCost: Int, maxLength: Int): Boolean = {
    maxLength > 0 &&
    maxCost >= 0 &&
    edges(start).exists(a =>
      (a._1 == end && a._2 <= maxCost) ||
      hasMaxCostPath(edges, a._1, end, maxCost - a._2, maxLength - 1)
    )
  }

  def getMaxCostPaths(
         edges: List[List[(Int, Int)]],
         from: Int, to: Int,
         maxCost: Int,
         maxLength: Int): List[List[Int]] = {
      getMaxCostPathsRec(edges, from, to, maxCost, maxLength, List(from))
  }

  def getMaxCostPathsRec(
         edges: List[List[(Int, Int)]],
         start: Int, end: Int,
         maxCost: Int,
         maxLength: Int,
         path: List[Int]) : List[List[Int]] = {
    if (maxLength <= 0 || maxCost < 0) return List()
    val direct = edges(start).filter(a => a._1 == end && a._2 <= maxCost).map(edge => path ::: List(edge._1))
    val transitive = edges(start).flatMap(a =>
      getMaxCostPathsRec(edges, a._1, end, maxCost - a._2, maxLength - 1, path ::: List(a._1))
    )
    direct ::: transitive
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. Any idea for the second def "getPaths"?

Comment: added a solution for this part.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. For the second problem I don't need the maxCost, only maxLength and how would I do this by initially using a "visited nodes" parameter (as I stated in the question), which also saves the cost of the path instead of the "path" parameter?

Comment: But the return type of the function is a list of only the costs of all possible paths from start node to end node